# Can I provide a HTML form for users to upload directly to S3 and can I create new sub folders for users?

Tags: html, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need to be able to provide an HTML form that allows users to upload a file to a particular bucket. I also need to be be to create a sub folder within the Bucket which relates to the users email (passed from the form).  If the sub folder exists then upload the file otherwise create a new folder etc.

Comment: You would need to use a programming language for this.

Comment: No, you can't do it directly from HTML. Also S3 does not have any folders, just key-value structure. You need to use some back-end or JS API of S3

Comment: Many People do it using different ways, the simple way would be to use some basic authentication and once your is successful, you can create a signed url and upload it using that, you can use js for that, e.gz; https://dev.filestack.com/ filestack does the exact same thing, once user is authenticated, it makes put request and upload the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use php to do that.  I wrote a phone script sometimes ago that can upload any image,  resize it and even move it from one folder to another, If I happen to come back online,  I could upload the script but you might need a little php experience to use it. So I suggest you try to learn php, most importantly OOP

Comment: Just to add, OP can also use JavaScript